# Turn a div into a link in HAML using a Rails link_to tag, with nested content within

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml

Sorry if this question doesn't make too much sense. I have a dropdown menu which expands. The first link in the menu that I want to expand on will be called "Overview". I want to use a link_to_function tag to expand the items  below Overview. However, I want the first link to say "Overview +" all on one line, with the "+" later changing to a "-" once the menu has expanded. I also want the +/- to be justified right, and "Overview" to be justified left. I've already implements the +/- change.

How can I do something like the following? Haml won't allow me to nest the links like this. The +/- change has already been implemented, so that part is working.

```
#main.section= link_to_function 'Overview', "toggleMenu('#main')"
  %a +
  %a -
```

Basically, I want the overall div to be the actual link, while the nested %a tags within are just there for formatting purposes. Of course, I could easily use JavaScript to put a listener on #main, but I want this to be dynamic so that I can expand multiple sections of the menu the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `do/end` block to the `link_to` method:

```
= link_to home_path do
  %span= "Go to"
  %span= "Home!"
```